# Periodically update files from s3 in a Java maven library used as Packaged JAR

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, akka

I have an application say x which uses another Java library(say Y) as a JAR file . So y basically needs to download a file and load it into memory before any of it's methods are called at runtime by X. How do I make sure that files are downloaded and loaded before any of the methods of y are called ? Also, Y is being used in multiples apps.

Should i use akka pattern here?

y is a Java framework used to detect useragent type. y is going to use a file to detect useragent stuff which needs to be downloaded from s3 and refreshed periodically and only then this library/framework should be used to detect type of useragent from X.

For example:

X is something like :

import com.data.Extract

```
public class X {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(Extract.getUserAgentInfo(args[0]));
  }
 }
```

pom.xml of X(Includes dependency of Y):

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>group-y</groupId>
         <artifactId>extract-data</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
```

Now before X calls getuseragentinfo, Y should have already loaded files into memory to get data from.

I'm wondering if I can use WatchService or Threading here to run a separate thread to just download the file and load into memory before this jar is being used .i.e. from inside the jar.

Please advise.